# Set output matrix on numpy binomial function

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, numpy, random

I want to use the following example in my project, which fills an array with random values using multiple threads.
https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/random/multithreading.html.

However, instead of the standard normal distribution I want to use a binomial distribution.
My problem is that the method [numpy.random.Generator.binomial](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.binomial.html#numpy.random.Generator.binomial) does not have an "out" argument (like the standard_normal method) where the result will be placed. This means that I will have to copy the output matrix given to me to my matrix, heavily decreasing performance.

Is there an alternative approach that will solve this issue?

If this helps, I actually need the Bernoulli distribution, i.e. n=1 in the binomial distribution (but an arbitrary p).

Comment: This may be a gap in NumPy.   If having an "out" argument for all Generator methods, not just `standard_normal`, is something you care about, file an issue in the [NumPy issues page](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues).

Comment: It's probably not going to take long either. Last time I asked about adding a dtype argument to the uniform integer routines and it got done fast

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked the statement "I will have to copy the output matrix given to me to my matrix, heavily decreasing performance"? Can you quantify "heavily"?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that this invalidates your question in an abstract sense by any means, but I have a suspicion that an extra copy of even a few million things is not going to be your bottleneck. In fact, if you have to lock the buffer to write to it, it might improve performance, since I'd expect the copy to be much faster than the generation of the numbers, hence less time spent waiting by everyone else.

Comment: What is dtype of your destination array?

Comment: Does the example code even work? It does not for me.

Answer (score 1):

The following code can use random generators both with and without support for the `out` parameter.
While, in general, the use of the `out` parameter result in faster execution, you can get some benefit in using parallel execution even in its absence.

```
import os
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np


def _rg_size(bit_gen, dist, num, *args, **kwargs):
    return getattr(np.random.Generator(bit_gen), dist)(size=num, *args, **kwargs)


def _rg_out(bit_gen, dist, out, *args, **kwargs):
    return getattr(np.random.Generator(bit_gen), dist)(out=out, *args, **kwargs)


def splitter(num, num_chunks):
    chunk_size = num // num_chunks + (1 if num % num_chunks else 0)
    while num > chunk_size:
        num -= chunk_size
        yield chunk_size
    yield num


def slicing_splitter(num, num_chunks):
    chunk_size = num // num_chunks + (1 if num % num_chunks else 0)
    i = 0
    remaining = num
    while remaining > chunk_size:
        remaining -= chunk_size
        yield slice(i, i + chunk_size)
        i += chunk_size
    yield slice(i, num)


def new_rgs(rg):
    while True:
        new_rg = rg.jumped()
        yield new_rg
        rg = new_rg


def glue(arrs, size, num_arrs=None):
    if num_arrs is None and hasattr(arrs, __len__):
        num_arrs = len(arrs)
    slicings = slicing_splitter(size, num_arrs)
    arrs = iter(arrs)
    arr = next(arrs)
    slicing = next(slicings)
    out = np.empty(size, dtype=arr.dtype)
    out[slicing] = arr
    for arr, slicing in zip(arrs, slicings):
        out[slicing] = arr
    return out


def parallel_rand_gen(
        num=None,
        dist='standard_normal',
        bit_gen=None,
        seed=None,
        out=None,
        num_workers=None,
        split_factor=1,
        *args,
        **kwargs):
    if num_workers is None:
        num_workers = min(32, os.cpu_count() + 1)
    if bit_gen is None:
        bit_gen = np.random.PCG64(seed)
    if out is not None:
        shape = out.shape
        out = out.ravel()
        num = out.size
    elif num is None:
        raise ValueError('Either `num` or `out` must be specified.')
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
        num_splits = split_factor * num_workers
        if out is None:
            futures = [
                executor.submit(_rg_size, rg, dist, n, *args, **kwargs)
                for rg, n in zip(new_rgs(bit_gen), splitter(num, num_splits))]
            concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
            result = (future.result() for future in futures)
            # out = np.concatenate(tuple(result))  # slower alternative
            out = glue(result, num, num_splits)
        else:
            futures = [
                executor.submit(_rg_out, rg, dist, out[slicing], *args, **kwargs)
                for rg, slicing in zip(new_rgs(bit_gen), slicing_splitter(num, num_splits))]
            concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
            out = out.reshape(shape)
    return out


print(parallel_rand_gen(17))
# [ 0.96710075  2.2935126   0.35537793  0.5825714   2.14440658  0.64483092
#   0.54062617  0.44907003  0.11947266 -0.60748694 -0.52509115  0.62924905
#   0.51714721  0.29864705 -0.46105766 -0.271093    0.33055528]
```

For `standard_normal` this gets to:

```
n = 10000001
%timeit parallel_rand_gen(n)
# 89.3 ms ± 1.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit out = np.empty(n); parallel_rand_gen(out=out)
# 74.6 ms ± 1.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit rg = np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64()); rg.standard_normal(n)
# 181 ms ± 7.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

and, for `binomial`, this gets to:

```
n = 10000001
%timeit parallel_rand_gen(n, 'binomial', n=100, p=0.5)
# 480 ms ± 15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit rg = np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64()); rg.binomial(100, 0.5, n)
# 1.17 s ± 35.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

(Tested on a 4-cores 6-years-old laptop.)

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.random.Generator.random](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.random.html) has an `out` argument if you want to draw uniform floats in `[0.0,1.0)`.

You can then just use:

```
def bernoulli(shape, p):
    U = uniform(shape) # can use multithreading
    return U < p       # should be fast enough
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you provided [This one](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/random/multithreading.html) i created the code:

```
from numpy.random import Generator, PCG64
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np

# to calculate the bernoulli randomness
from scipy.stats import bernoulli

# use this to see the results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#benchmark the multi threading
from time import time

class MultithreadedRNG(object):
    def __init__(self, n, seed=None, number_of_threads=None):
        rg = PCG64(seed)
        if number_of_threads is None:
            number_of_threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        self.number_of_threads = number_of_threads

        self._random_generators = [rg]
        last_rg = rg
        for _ in range(0, number_of_threads-1):
            new_rg = last_rg.jumped()
            self._random_generators.append(new_rg)
            last_rg = new_rg

        self.n = n
        self.executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(number_of_threads) # use this  object to multithread
        self.value_array = np.empty(n) # reserve the array memory
        self.step = np.ceil(n / number_of_threads).astype(np.int_) # round up to get the number of steps

    def _thread_fill(self, rg, out, first, last):
        p = 0.3

        # x = np.random.randn(N_points) # this uses a normal distribution
        self.value_array[first:last] = bernoulli.rvs(p, size=len(out[first:last]))
        #self.value_array[first:last] = np.random.standard_normal(len(out[first:last]))

    def fill(self):

        futures = {}
        for i in range(self.number_of_threads):
            args = (
                self._thread_fill,
                self._random_generators[i],
                self.value_array,
                i * self.step,
                (i + 1) * self.step
                )

            # this is a simple object to signal is complete
            futures[self.executor.submit(*args)] = i

        # wait for all the proccess to finish
        concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

    def __del__(self):
        self.executor.shutdown(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    arr_size = 1000000

    # populate using multi thread
    mrng = MultithreadedRNG(arr_size, seed=0)
    multi_thread_time1 = time()
    mrng.fill()
    mrng.__del__()
    print("Multi thread time: ", time() - multi_thread_time1)

    # populate using single thread
    single_thread_time1 = time()
    vec = np.random.standard_normal(arr_size)
    print("Single thread time: ", time() - single_thread_time1)

    # see the results
    print("Results: ", mrng.value_array)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=False)
    axs[0].hist(vec, bins=30)
    axs[0].set_title('Standard distribution')
    axs[1].hist(mrng.value_array, bins=30)
    axs[1].set_title('Bernouli distribution')
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

You can then change the "p" value of the bernoulli distribution. An example run looks like this:

[image: Output graph]